# How To copy specific jpg files from a directory based on their name matching txt files?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to know a command to copy specific jpg images from a directory based on text file names in another directory.

Comment: what's your actual question? what's the problem? is there an error? if so, what is it?   is it not doing what you expect? if so, then what is it doing and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: I had this problem of copying image files based on text file names. I searched for answer but I couldn't able to get one. So after some struggle I could able to get the answer. Thought sharing that would be useful to others.

Comment: ok, that's good. but you should ask a question and then post an answer to your question. you can then accept your own answer after a day or so (or if someone else posts another answer you like better, you can accept that).

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I am able to develop.

```
cp to/txtfile/directory
for file in *; do 
  cp -r "source/image_directory/${file%.*}jpg" dest/image_directory/;
done
```

Thanks to @Philippos for suggesting a more generalised .

We can also apply the same logic for moving the files.

Comment: I'd suggest instead of using `bash` substring expansion (`${file::-3}`) use the portable and perhaps more robust `${file%.*}` to remove the filename extension.

Comment: Thank you @Philippos. Your solution looks more elegant. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With zsh:

```
(){ cp -- $jpgdir/$^@.jpg $destdir; } $txtdir/*.txt(:t:r)
```